# Speeding up window resize function performance

Tags: javascript

I have some script similar to the following:

```
var breakpoints = [0,240,480,960,9999],
    bpCount = breakpoints.length,
    windowsize = 0;

window.onresize = function() {

    windowsize = document.body.clientWidth;

    for(var i=0; i<bpCount; i++) {
        if(windowsize >= breakpoints[i] && windowsize < breakpoints[i+1]) {
            doSomething(breakpoints[i]);
            break;
        }
    }    

};
```

However this seems to run pretty slowly, even in Chrome on a decent PC, and even when 'doSomething' is just performing a 'console.log', so I was just wondering if there was any better way of checking whether the screen size is between two values as it resizes?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a little function throttling/debouncing can help, for example using the underscore library: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#throttle

Comment: Do you only want to `doSomething()` once for each range?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't poll for the size *every single time*. You're using way too much computing power.

Instead, make a timer and check for the size every so often (`10 ms` might be too fast):

```
var checkWindowSizeTimer;

function checkWindowSize() {
    var windowsize = document.body.clientWidth;

    if (windowsize >= breakpoints[i] && windowsize < breakpoints[i+1]) {
        doSomething(breakpoints[i]);
        clearInterval(checkWindowSizeTimer);
    }
}

window.onresize = function() {
  checkWindowSizeTimer = setInterval(checkWindowSize, 10);
}
```

When the window is resized past your bounds, the timer exits.

Comment: Won't delaying the function slow down the effect even more? I am basically just wondering if there is a quicker way of checking which range a particular number is in.

Comment: It'll slow down what you want to do, but much, much less than your method. The user doesn't move the mouse fast enough to notice.