# Run javascript function on load

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use this script to run a function on the page load. Can anyone see what's wrong?  Stupid error, I'm sure - just can't work it out.

Code:

```
<script>

  var text = document.getElementById("myText");

  function changeFontSize(){
  if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
text.style.fontSize = "70px";
      } else {
      text.style.fontSize = "100px";
      }
  }

  window.onresize = changeFontSize;

  </script>

  <script>
  setTimeout(function() changeFontSize, 3000);
  </script>
```

Comment: Try to use window.onload  = changeFontSize;

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = changeFontSize;
window.onresize = changeFontSize;
```

alternatively, you can use

```
window.addEventListener("onload", changeFontSize, false);
window.addEventListener("onresize", changeFontSize, false);
```

Comment: tried that but it didn't work - i want the javascript to run once when the window is loaded and then with the listener for whenever it is resized.

Comment: ok it's working now :) but it is quite slow, there's a good one-two second wait until it runs it. Any ideas?

Comment: yes, that is because onresize is demanding too much cpu power. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040092/speeding-up-window-resize-function-performance

Comment: really? I have an 8 core cpu so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: also, I am using this code: http://pastebin.com/GJi0KZyS but it isn't working on resize any more...

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var text = document.getElementById("myText");

  function changeFontSize() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
      text.style.fontSize = "70px";
    } else {
      text.style.fontSize = "100px";
    }
  }

  window.onresize = changeFontSize;

  setTimeout(changeFontSize, 3000);
```

```html
<p id="myText">Test</p>
```

Basically you had a syntax error in:

```
setTimeout(function()  changeFontSize, 3000);
```

You don't need the `function()`

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work either...I would like to run the function once when the page is loaded and then whenever it is resized.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var text = document.getElementById("myText");

  function changeFontSize(){
  if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
text.style.fontSize = "70px";
      } else {
      text.style.fontSize = "100px";
      }
  }

  window.onload = changeFontSize;
  window.onresize = changeFontSize;
```

```html
<div id="myText">Test</div>
```

Comment: thanks but it didn't work. the javascript should run once on the load of page/timeout and then whenever windows is resized.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, `setTimeout()` isn't used the way you wrote it, it should be `setTimeout(changeFontSize, 3000);` instead. That being said this would work:

```
<script>
    var text = document.getElementById("myText");

    function changeFontSize() {
        if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
            text.style.fontSize = "70px";
        } else {
            text.style.fontSize = "100px";
        }
    }

    window.onresize = changeFontSize;

    changeFontSize();
</script>
```

As was also said by jperelli, `window.onload = changeFontSize` would also work.

Comment: thanks but it didn't work. the javascript should run once on the load of page/timeout and then whenever windows is resized.

Comment: @dwinnbrown Are you putting the `<script>` block in the `<head>` tags or at the end of the body (after the elements you want to re-size)? What's the behavior that you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want absolutely use `onresize` instead `onload` (I suppose that you want to achieve something responsive), you need to wait the page is loaded, otherwise the object *myText* will not the object will not yet been initialized in the variable text ('cause it's not yet available in the DOM).
Note that in this case the use of a `setTimeout` (you wrong the syntax anyway) is not necessary.

This works:

```
<script>

  function changeFontSize(){
      if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
          document.getElementById("myText").style.fontSize = "70px";
      } else {
          document.getElementById("myText").style.fontSize = "100px";
      }
  }

  window.onresize = changeFontSize;

</script>
```

Comment: thanks but it didn't work. the javascript should run once on the load of page/timeout and then whenever windows is resized.